# How to use error_condition in boost::system library?

Tags: c++, boost, system

Is it necessary to use it when I return my error_code from functions? I think it is necessary to pass the single object which class is derived from error_category to error_code object with my error value.
I also provide the error message in my category class. 
So error_condition is necessary to use? What is the difference between it and error_code?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [this article](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-2.html):

> - class error_code - represents a specific error value returned by an operation (such as a system call).
> - class error_condition - something that you want to test for and, potentially, react to in your code.

Instead of comparing `error_code::value` with some OS-specific value, one should compare `error_code` against portable `error_condition`.